# Datatables Tabletools print mode shows all data. In need of only what was previously displayed

Tags: jquery, datatables, tabletools

I made Tabletools to work, although I am struggling with the print mode.
Once the button is hit, the print mode is run correctly, only displaying the records shown previously. Within a second, the rest of the data is also shown.
Has anyone encountered the same issue? Is it possible that my jQuery code is triggering this action? Thanks in advance.

Comment: would be better if you can share code.

Comment: @Burak even though I pointed my code to be the issue, it is highly unlikely to be, because I am using an unaltered version of Table Tools js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind guys, I have just found my answer in the functionality [site](http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/button_options#Print-button-options).

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "oTableTools": {
        "aButtons": [
            {
                "sExtends": "print",
                "bShowAll": false
            }
        ]
    }
} );
```

} );